# Defining a TikZ style to scale the content of a node

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxes

I am trying to define a `scale content=<factor>` style to be applied to node objects in TikZ pictures. It's purpose is to scale the content of the node without changing the node's outer dimensions. I got relatively far with the following definition:

```
% Key to scale the content of a node by a factor #1
\tikzset{scale content/.style={
  execute at begin node={
    \numdef{\scale@content@nest}{\scale@content@nest+1} % increase nesting counter
    \ifnumequal{\scale@content@nest}{1}{                % do not nest 
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\scale@content}{#1}
      \begin{lrbox}{\@tempboxa}
      \ifx\tikz@text@width\pgfutil@empty\else
        % if 'text width' has been specified it must been scaled reciprocally
        % we achieve this by typesetting in a accordingly dimensioned minipage
        \pgfmathsetlength{\@tempdima}{\tikz@text@width/#1}
        \begin{minipage}{\@tempdima}
      \fi
    }{}
  }, 
  execute at end node={
    \ifnumequal{\scale@content@nest}{1}{
      \ifx\tikz@text@width\pgfutil@empty\else
        \end{minipage}
      \fi
      \end{lrbox}
      \scalebox{\scale@content}{\usebox\@tempboxa}
    }{}
    \numdef{\scale@content@nest}{\scale@content@nest-1} % decrease nesting counter
  }
}}
```

This works well, unless I specify `text width` depending on `\textwidth` as shown in the third example below (complete MWE):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,etoolbox}
\makeatletter

% Key to scale the content of a node by a factor #1
\tikzset{scale content/.style={
  execute at begin node={
    \numdef{\scale@content@nest}{\scale@content@nest+1} % increase nesting counter
    \ifnumequal{\scale@content@nest}{1}{                % do not nest 
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\scale@content}{#1}
      \begin{lrbox}{\@tempboxa}
      \ifx\tikz@text@width\pgfutil@empty\else
        % if 'text width' has been specified, scale it accordingly by using a minipage
        \pgfmathsetlength{\@tempdima}{\tikz@text@width/#1}
        \begin{minipage}{\@tempdima}
      \fi
    }{}
  }, 
  execute at end node={
    \ifnumequal{\scale@content@nest}{1}{
      \ifx\tikz@text@width\pgfutil@empty\else
        \end{minipage}
      \fi
      \end{lrbox}
      \scalebox{\scale@content}{\usebox\@tempboxa}
    }{}
    \numdef{\scale@content@nest}{\scale@content@nest-1} % decrease nesting counter
  }
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \tikzset{every node/.style={draw, fill=yellow!40}}

  \tikz\node[text width=3cm]{Not scaled, text width is 3cm};
  \par
  \tikz\node[scale content=0.7, text width=3cm]{scaled by 0.7, text width is 3cm, everything is fine};
  \par
  \tikz\node[scale content=0.7, text width=0.5\textwidth, text=red]{scaled by 0.7, text width is 0.5\textbackslash textwidth, so why aren't we using it?};
  \par
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\mywidth}{0.5\textwidth}
  \tikz\node[scale content=0.7, text width=\mywidth]{scaled by 0.7, text width is 0.5\textbackslash textwidth, manually expanded before, so this is how it should look like};
\end{document}
```

[image: screen shot]

Apparently, TikZ does not expand `text width` directly, which would solve the problem:

```
% original definition from tikz.code.tex:779
\tikzoption{text width}{\def\tikz@text@width{#1}}

% Alternative definition that would work
\tikzoption{text width}{\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\tikz@text@width}{#1}}
```

However, once I am inside `execute at begin node` it seems already to be to late, apparently `\textwidth` has already be transformed somehow.

So how can I get the expanded value of a node's `text width`?

Or should I take a completely different route?

Comment: You have a couple of spurious spaces in your code. You should add `%` directly after each `{` or `}` appearing at the end of the line.

Comment: Also note the existance of the `adjustbox` package which allows  for `\begin{adjustbox}{scale=<factor>} ... \end{adjustbox}` which could replace the `lrbox`/`\scalebox` combination. It effectively does the same internally. However your current code is more efficient.

Comment: @Martin: Actually, I do use `adjustbox`in my real implementation and I like it pretty much :-) I only substituted it for this MWE, so that others do not have to download an extra package that is not yet part of standard latex installations. (PS: Thanks for the spurious spaces hint!)

Comment: I see :-) The `adjustbox` package is part of the current TeXLive and MikTeX. However,  "standard LaTeX installations" like the one of Ubuntu unfortunately use an older version :-(

Comment: `text width/.evaluated=0.5\textwidth` or `text width/.expanded=0.5*\the\textwidth`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\textwidth` macro is changed by a `minipage` to the given width. Now, TikZ already uses a `minipage` itself if `text width` is used. The solution would be to use the new `\textwidth` for scaling instead of `\tikz@text@width`. Otherwise a `text width` value relative to the outer `\textwidth` would be taken into account twice!

You can find the relevant code in `tikz.code.tex` starting at line 3116:

```
\ifx\tikz@text@width\pgfutil@empty%
\else%
  \begingroup%
    \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@x}{\tikz@text@width}%
    \pgfutil@minipage[t]{\pgf@x}\leavevmode\hbox{}%
      \tikz@text@action%
\fi%
\tikz@atbegin@node%
```

Here `\pgfutil@minipage` is the normal `\minipage` macro (i.e. ~`\begin{minipage}`) and `\tikz@atbegin@node` is where the `execute at begin node` is inserted.

Applied to your MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,etoolbox}
\makeatletter

% Key to scale the content of a node by a factor #1
\tikzset{scale content/.style={
  execute at begin node={
    \numdef{\scale@content@nest}{\scale@content@nest+1} % increase nesting counter
    \ifnumequal{\scale@content@nest}{1}{                % do not nest 
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\scale@content}{#1}
      \begin{lrbox}{\@tempboxa}
      \ifx\tikz@text@width\pgfutil@empty\else
        % if 'text width' has been specified, scale it accordingly by using a minipage
        % Here `\textwidth` now represents the original text width of the node.
        \pgfmathsetlength{\@tempdima}{\textwidth/\scale@content}
        \begin{minipage}{\@tempdima}
      \fi
    }{}
  }, 
  execute at end node={
    \ifnumequal{\scale@content@nest}{1}{
      \ifx\tikz@text@width\pgfutil@empty\else
        \end{minipage}
      \fi
      \end{lrbox}
      \scalebox{\scale@content}{\usebox\@tempboxa}
    }{}
    \numdef{\scale@content@nest}{\scale@content@nest-1} % decrease nesting counter
  }
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \tikzset{every node/.style={draw, fill=yellow!40}}

  \tikz\node[text width=3cm]{Not scaled, text width is 3cm};
  \par
  \tikz\node[scale content=0.7, text width=3cm]{scaled by 0.7, text width is 3cm, everything is fine};
  \par
  \tracingassigns=1
  \tikz\node[scale content=0.7, text width=0.5\textwidth, text=red]{scaled by 0.7, text width is 0.5\textbackslash textwidth, so why aren't we using it?};
  \par
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\mywidth}{0.5\textwidth}
  \tikz\node[scale content=0.7, text width=\mywidth]{scaled by 0.7, text width is 0.5\textbackslash textwidth, manually expanded before, so this is how it should look like};
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: @Daniel: You are welcome. BTW: I didn't fixed the spaces in this code example but simply copied your original code.