# Tikz: Style which only scale the text inside a node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikzscale

I am looking for some possibility to only scale the text inside a node without using the commands like \tiny or \scriptsize.

In my styleset I am using the line

```
every node/.style={font=\scriptsize, very thin, scale=.7}
```

This do a scaling of the font, however also scales the dimensions of the node. I want to achieve that my picture is getting excatly the correct width without using just resizebox as this cann result that all my pictures have slightly diffferent font sizes and line widths.

Using the fonts \tiny and \sriptsize is no option for me as ,in my opionion, they look very ugly due to the horizontal stretch.

So is there as easy possibility to just use a global option that all content inside a node is scaled using a given factor?

Found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21856/defining-a-tikz-style-to-scale-the-content-of-a-node) however this post was 7 years ago and I do not completely understand the added code. Maybe there is a new implementation using newer functions of Tikz?

Comment: Tikz nodes fit the text inside, so if you reduce the size of the text, the node will shrink accordingly, except for the line width and inner sep.  BTW, there is also \small and \footnotesize.  See also the tikzscale package.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

just for fun an experiment using `anyfontsize` package, showing the variation of font size from 1 to 20 pt in the node 3; node 2 is scaled from 0.1 to 2.0...

RESULT:

[image]

MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes, action: nonstopmode}
% arara: animate: {density: 100, delay: 20 , other: -background white -alpha remove}
% arara: showanimate
\documentclass[border=20pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
    \foreach \x in {1,...,20}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (-2.5,7) rectangle (10,-7);
    \pgfmathparse{\x/10}
    \edef\s{\pgfmathresult}
    \draw
        node[draw,text width=3cm](N1){Node 1\\ The text width is 3cm. in normal size font.}
        node[below right= 1 and 1 of N1,draw,text width=3cm,scale=\x/10](N2){Node 2\\ The text width is 3cm. in normal size font. but all is scaled \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=1]{\s}}
        node[above right= 1 and 1 of N1,draw,text width=3cm,font=\fontsize{\x}{10}\selectfont](N3){Node 3\\ The text width is 3cm. and size font is changed to \x};
    \fill[red,opacity=0.5]
        (N1.center) circle (2pt)
        (N2.center) circle (2pt)
        (N3.center) circle (2pt);;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{document}
```

PSD: to animate I use the imagemagick converter.